# Disable callbacks in PhantomJS (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, c#, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS for a UI testing framework in C#. I am trying to click an element, which displays a confirm box, in one action and then return to the calling C# with the confirm box still open. Then, I am trying to call back into PhantomJS to click 'OK' on the dialog box in a second action.

The problem is that there is a callback attached to the confirm box which returns true/false (OK/Cancel), so the default behaviour just cancels the confirm box. I can attach my own custom callback, taking the message passed to the actual ( var result = confirm('message') ) call, like so:

```
page.onConfirm = function(msg) {
    console.log('Confirmation box showing for: ' + msg);
    return someBooleanValue;
}
```

But because of the truthy/falsey stuff in javascript, whatever I return here will either OK or cancel the confirm dialog - I can't seem to just leave it open.

It's worth mentioning that I am trying to still to plain javascript as opposed to introducing JQuery because it is a testing framework.

Any ideas how I do this?

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone having the same issue, essentially the answer is that you can't do this. I just wound up having to define a default behaviour for these callbacks.